# Is there a design pattern for this kind of construction code?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public class A {
    private A(int param1, String param2) {}

    public static A createFromCursor(Cursor c) {
        // calculate param1 and param2 from cursor
        return new A(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Is there a design pattern for this kind of construction code? If so, what's the purpose of this pattern? Why not just use:

```
// calculate param1 and param2 from cursor
new A(param1, param2);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static factory method for constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029622/static-factory-method-for-constructors)

Comment: Since this isn't valid Java, it seems moot to consider it a design pattern.

Comment: @Dancrumb what's invalid here?

Comment: @dantuch: It has been edited. It's correct now

Comment: In Soviet Java factories created by factories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to sum up.

That pattern is called **Static Factory Method** and it's described for example here: [How to use "Static factory methods" instead of constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029622/static-factory-method-for-constructors)

In simplest form it looks like this:

```
 class A {

     public static A newA() {
        return new A();
     }
     private A(){}
 }
```

Your example is little bit more complex as it includes computing parameters for invoking constructor

```
public class A {
    private A(int param1, String param2) {}

    public static A createFromCursor(Cursor c) {
        // calculate param1 and param2 from cursor
        return new A(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

The purpose of using such way for creating new object may be the need to repeat those calculating every time before calling `new A(params)` directly. So it's just avoiding repeating yourself, and simplest way to achieve this is creating a method.

Furthermore using the same way, you can provide even more options to create `new A`. For example you can change the way your calculation works with:

```
    public static A createFromCursorDifferently(Cursor c) {
        // calculate param1 and param2 from cursor in different way
        return new A(param1, param2);
    }
```

Then you may pass the same parameter to this method, and result will be different (coz method name is varies).

And of course you can create your `new A` from any other parameter, using the same constructor as before:

```
    public static A createFromObject(Object o) {
        // calculate param1 and param2 from object
        return new A(param1, param2);
    }
```

So you have much more possibilities with **Static Factory Methods** than with simple usage of constructors only.

Comment: I think you missed two of the common uses of this pattern. One is that the static method can choose which class to instantiate -- it can do something like `if (conditionA) return new A(...) else return new B(...)`. The other is to allow a caller to instantiate a class whose constructor, for whatever reason, you don't want to expose publicly (for instance, because you want to limit who can create subclasses of it). `ByteBuffer` is a good example of this.

Comment: @yshavit you're right, but I tried stick to given question, not to describe whole nature of this pattern, and factoring as general :)

Answer (score 2):

If your code compiled, it would represent a simple [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_object) (it returns a static what? an A of course). Some consider this a pattern, but others don't as it is very simplistic. There is a pattern called the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that uses this concept, but in a much more complex fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the thing you posted should be, if corrected, the one of providing a method to return an instance of something that `extends A` without the necessity to know the runtime type a priori.

So yes, it sounds similar to a [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) although it's somewhat different from what you wrote. The *factory* class should be different from the *product* class.

Comment: `The factory class should be different from the product class.` that's true, that's why the code provided as a sample is example of **Static Factory Method**, as pointed by @Tomasz Nurkiewicz. And that static method should be placed in the same class that it is factoring, just to replace explicit constructor. It is well described in "Effective Java" - one of the most recommended books for java programmers