# How to restrict a class attribute to 6 characters and make it so that it is initially 3 characters and 3 numeric values afterwards?

Tags: java

I have an class called car with attributes and one of those attributes being a license number which I have to show printed and it must fulfil being only 6 chars long and having 3 characters and 3 numbers as such: ASF817

Also if somebody inputted their license plate number being wrong, how would I tell print some code to say it is wrong?

I'm not sure of what method to use at all to restrict to exactly specific values.

```
public class Car {
private String regNo;
private String make;
private String model;
private String driverName;
private int passengerCapacity;
private boolean available;
private String[] Booking = {"currentBookings, pastBookings"};

public Car(String regNo, String make, String model, 
String driverName, int passengerCapacity) {
    this.regNo = regNo;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.driverName = driverName;
    if(passengerCapacity < 0) 
    {
        this.passengerCapacity = 1;
    }
    else if(passengerCapacity > 10) 
    {
        this.passengerCapacity = 10;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.passengerCapacity = passengerCapacity;
    } 
    System.out.println(this.passengerCapacity);
```

Need to make String regNo only be 6 chars, with 3 characters first and 3 numeric values after when inputted by a user. Thank you.

Comment: What you describe is called validation. One of the most basic ways to do that would be to do the checks in the setter and/or constructor and throwing an exception if the check fails.

Comment: A simple [regex comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) would work (`/[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/`) but you would have to do that when getting the user input or else throw an exception in the constructor.

Comment: @Thomas how would i do this? I find it hard to navigate the web and get information that relates to this. Im a bit lost sorry

Comment: How would you do what? The check itself? That would be by using some regex, e.g. `regNo.matches("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}")`. Throwing an exception if the check fails? That would be something like `throw new SomeException()` - and you might want to read up on exceptions in general first if you're not familiar with them yet.

Comment: Check this post, they have an example there that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803650/java-how-to-only-create-an-object-with-valid-attributes