# How can I use the builder pattern to construct various similar object types?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

I am currently using the builder pattern as defined here:

[Previous question showing my use of the builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302891/the-builder-pattern-and-a-large-number-of-mandatory-parameters)

The problem I've now encountered is a requirement to create the following structure:

```
- ZipHolder: file metadata present
    * File mainFile
    * File optionalFile
    * List<File> files
```

OR:

```
- ZipHolder: no file metadata present
    * File mainFile
    * File optionalFile
    * List<File> files
```

Both `ZipHolder` and `File` are constructed using the builder pattern, implemented as an internal static class of each. A `ZipHolder` takes a `mainFile` as a mandatory constructor parameter and prefills some information in the `ZipHolder`, which can be overridden, should the need arise. A `File` contains file content and associated metadata pertaining to that file. Validation on both the `ZipHolder` and `File` is then performed when calling the `build()` method of each's `Builder` class. The objects are then taken and output to a ZIP file hierarchy that should then be read in to the same object structure, if required.

This works nicely and gives a degree of flexibility in object creation while ensuring immutability. I have encountered a problem though. A new requirement has presented itself, mandating that `File` objects can either have metadata **and** file content *OR* **only** file content. I figured I could simply pass a boolean flag value to the builder for the `ZipHolder` object to allow the skipping of the usual metadata validation. This would seem ok but then it requires a `File` *mainFile* to be constructed - essentially, a chicken and egg situation. My next thought was to move the flag to the `File` class. This seemed ok until I realised that you could potentially create multiple `File` objects, some with metadata required and others with only the file content, with no means of enforcing constraints across the board.

So I am somewhat stumped as to how to proceed. I can't see an obvious means of decoupling the requirement of a *mainFile* for a `ZipHolder` in an elegant fashion. Concepts like abstract classes, interfaces, base classes and things like that come to mind but I'm in need of some direction in this particular situation.

So my question is:

Can I allow for both scenarios while retaining the builder pattern per the reasons in my link above?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand the problem but you should probably make a class `MainFile extends File`, implement constraints there and require the user to pass a MainFile instance to ZipHolder factory.

Comment: Sorry about my late response. The issue is more or less the need to have subclasses of a base class. The sub class, in my example, will then have the additional file content. So I guess considering there's an inner static builder class in each File-type class, I'm not so sure on how best to go about what essentially amounts to duplication of effort. My aims with the builder pattern are immutability, ease of building complex objects with optional/mandatory params, and validation. So I guess to take it one step further, is using the builder pattern the right fit for what I want to achieve.