# How to create a Class with multiple constructors that use the same parameter type

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public class Arquivo {

    private File diretorio  = null ;

    public Arquivo(File dir){
        this.diretorio = dir;
    }

    public Arquivo(String dir){
        this( new File(dir) );
    }

    public Arquivo(String fileName){
        this( new File("./src/Data/"+fileName) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't with constructor, that is one of the limitation of constructors

time to start using [static factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

---

**See Also**

- [What are static factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java)

Comment: Also, consider how you would _use_ such a pair of constructors. What do you expect `new Arquivo("foo")` would do? Which constructor would it call?

Comment: @ysha I could wrap the construction logic in conjunction with setters inside my factory method or I would use Builder pattern

Comment: Sorry, the "you" there was meant for the OP. :) I was getting at the fact that if Java did allow two constructors with the same signature, it would make usages of those constructors ambiguous. I +1'd your answer -- factory methods are the way to go here.

Comment: Some more further reading: *[Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683)*, Item 1, "[Consider static factory methods instead of constructors](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec1)".

Answer (score 3):

You can't create two constructors that receive a single `String` parameter, there can only exist one such constructor. There *must* be a difference between the signatures, for example, add a second parameter to one of the constructors.

Alternatively, you could create a single constructor and indicate in a second parameter whether it's a file or a directory:

```
// isFile == true means it's a file. isFile == false means it's a directory
public Arquivo(String fileName, boolean isFile) {
    this(new File((isFile ? "./src/Data" : "") + fileName));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A constructor can not do that

a lazy solution would be

```
public Arquivo(String s) {}

public Arquivo(String s, boolean b) {}
```

and just don't use the boolean

Comment: is there a way to do something similar to this, however, using the the most resource-friendly path ?. the solution you provided may be more suitable for the occasion, otherwise, i would have to change some extra code in my project.

Comment: It can be really, really confusing to use a 'magic boolean'.  Coders not expecting this may waste time hunting down a boolean in the code that doesn't exist, and may presume one was deleted (by accident? Who knows?) without documentation.

Comment: like you said `without documentation`, which is not right in its own.
then i again i said `a lazy solution`, i agree with you however.