# Is it possible to initialize a generic variable with a specific-typed value?

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

I have a class that I want to be instantiated with either a `String` or `int` value, and I define the corresponding instance variable `value` as generic type `T`:

```
public class MathValue<T extends Object> {
    private boolean isOperand, isOperator;

    // a generic-typed instance variable:
    private T value;

    // constructor:
    public MathValue(int operand) {

        // compile-error -- "Incompatible types: required T, found Integer"
        this.value = new Integer(operand);

        this.isOperand = true;
        this.isOperator = false;
    }

    // constructor:
    public MathValue(String operator) {

        // compile-error -- "Incompatible types: required T, found String"
        this.value = operand;

        this.isOperand = false;
        this.isOperator = true;
    }
}
```

I *could* very well have a single constructor instead, with a formal parameter of type `T`, but I want to enforce the class' instantiation with a `String` or `int` argument:

```
public class MathValue<T extends Object> {
    private boolean isOperand, isOperator;

    // a generic-typed instance variable:
    private T value;

    // it totally works, but does not enforce specific-typed instantiation:
    public MathValue(T operandOrOperator) {
        this.value = operandOrOperator;

        if (operandOrOperator instanceof Integer) {
            this.isOperand = true;
            this.isOperator = false;

        } else if (operandOrOperator instanceof String) {
            this.isOperand = false;
            this.isOperator = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So despite the logical error of wanting to make a generic-typed class "not so generic", is it possible to instantiate a generic variable with a specific-typed value?

Comment: `T extends TheSpecificTypesMustUnifyHere`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, as `String` and `Integer` are in a different type hierarchy, and only common supertype is `Object`. What you can however do is, throw an unchecked exception from the constructor, if `T` is not an instance of either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create factory methods.  Here's now it might look:

```
public class MathValue<T extends Object> {

    public static MathValue<String> from(String s) {
        MathValue<String> mv = new MathValue<String>();

        mv.setValue(s);
        mv.setIsOperand(true);
        return mv;
    }

     public static MathValue<Integer> from(Integer s) {
        MathValue<Integer> mv = new MathValue<Integer>();

        mv.setValue(i);
        mv.setIsOperand(false);
        return mv;
    }

    // Rest of your class below
}
```

If you absolutely need a constructor (eg, you don't know the type that you're creating for ahead of time), then I can't see a way around @RohitJain 's suggestion.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @bstempi for the information! Might this be a common design pattern for a problem like this?

Comment: This is the [static factory pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java).  It's applicable here because you have some specific types of `T` that you're concerned with.  Generally, this is a poor approach if you have more than a handful of type `T` to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sub-classes.  Define an abstract class to actually store the value, generically:

```
abstract class MathValue<T> {
        private final T value;

        MathValue(T value) {
                this.value = value;
        }

        abstract boolean isOperator();

        boolean isOperand() {
                return !isOperator();
        }
}
```

Then one subclass that enforces the value type to be an integer.

```
class OperandValue extends MathValue<Integer> {

        OperandValue(int operand) {
                super(new Integer(operand));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOperator() {
                return false;
        }
}
```

and another subtype that enforces it to be a String.

```
class OperatorValue extends MathValue<String> {

        OperatorValue(String operator) {
                super(operator);
        }

        @Override
        boolean isOperator() {
                return true;
        }
}
```

With this design, you don't actually need to store the Booleans.

(Note, for simplicity I left out the visibility keywords.)