# Why does VelocityTracker not use a constructor?

Tags: java, android

Android's [VelocityTracker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) does not use a constructor, but rather if the object reference is null, you use `variableName = VelocityTracker.obtain()`. I have never seen something like this in Java before. Is this a standard design pattern, and why is it used?

Comment: Factory method, it returns an instance as opposed to using constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are static factory methods in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a factory method. (At least) in Android, `obtain()` is a conventional method name for classes that implement recycling under the hood. They usually come with a `recycle()` method that you run on an object when you no longer need it (another good example is `Message`). That is, they keep track of a pool of objects and, whenever there comes a need for a new object, you call `obtain()` which may return an already created instance instead of allocating memory for a new one.