# Can a Java constructor return already existing object of same type?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor, new-operator

Whenever we call a constructor in Java, it creates a new object and returns its reference in the end (of newly created object).

Is there any possibility that a Java constructor does not create a new object but return the reference to an already created object?

```
// Is it possible that myObject is not a new object, its already existing object
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

I have a list of objects of some class, and based on few parameters in constructor sometimes it more efficient that I don't create a new object, instead I pick up an already existing object. Is there is any other way?

Comment: In a word, no. What is the genesis for this question?

Comment: No, that's not possible. But it is possible to use an object pool or to use a creational pattern and reuse a previously created object.

Comment: Just trying to make program more efficient, don't wanna use the pool. I thought there might be something like that.

Comment: Make a private constructor and a static method which plays the role of a factory for the object you  want to create. Then if you need to create a new Object call the constructor and return its result (new object). If you do not need a new object return a existing one which you have stored in some static variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Constructors by definition run when a new object is created to initialize it. If the constructor is run, a new object has already come into existence, and there's nothing you can do about it.

What you could do is make a static method which either creates a new object, or returns an existing one. This is the standard approach in such cases.

Say, [`Boolean.valueOf(boolean value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-boolean-) in the standard library exists for the purpose of avoiding creation of extra objects. You can create them using `new Boolean(value)`, but it is much better to call this method because it will return the same object for the same values.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do this using constructors but you could use one of the patterns mentioned below.

If you only ever need 1 object then use the [Singleton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) pattern.

If your might have a few variations then use [Flyweight](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm) pattern as duffymo mentioned.

As duffymo mentions in his comment below - if you using any of these patterns then its important from a concurrency perspective to understand that these objects will be global state - you should therefore ensure they are immutable, and if you cannot make them immutable then you may want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Please don't use the Singleton pattern.  It's a global variable.  Google has gone to great lengths to expunge Singleton from their code.  You should, too.  https://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/wiki/WhySingletonsAreControversial

Comment: Good call duffymo. But these patterns are safe if you take the steps to ensure they are immutable objects - doesn't always fit though.

Comment: Nope, global variables aren't a good idea.  Thread safety is assumed.

Comment: It's not assumed if you know how to make objects truly immutable. But if you are not very experienced with Java then it's a good approach to avoid global variables.

Comment: I understand thread safety.  I also understand why global variables aren't a good idea, so I wouldn't recommend Singleton.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. Create a static method to create objects based on required logic and don't forget to make constructor private.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

[JLS section 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9):

> Unqualified class instance creation expressions begin with the keyword `new`.
>
> An unqualified class instance creation expression may be used to **create** an instance of a class, regardless of whether the class is a top level (§7.6), member (§8.5, §9.5), local (§14.3), or anonymous class (§15.9.5).

and [JLS section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> A new class instance is **explicitly created** when evaluation of a class instance creation expression (§15.9) causes a class to be instantiated. 
>   
> ...
>   Just before a reference to the **newly created object is returned** as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure: [...]

Notice that this clearly mentions creation of objects and not a possibe re-utilization.

---

On the other hand, you could create a static factory for your object that uses a pool. You could take a look at the implementation of [`Integer.valueOf(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) for example. [Refer to this answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929273/1743880).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with just a constructor in Java.

If required, such a behaviour is achieved by using either static method inside the class (like `Integer.valueOf(0)`) or the whole dedicated object of the different class (like `DocumentBuilderFactory`) to return the instances. This provides enough control to substitute the existing object instead of always creating a new one.

As a rule, such objects should be immutable and thread safe to be  easily shareable. Also, instance reuse and sometimes caching is implemented along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

No. Class provides the blueprint for objects, when using the `new` operator it is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes new object.
[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

If you wish to reuse objects for any reasons you may want considering implement the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) as well as the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) into your project for best result.