# What is the name of the of/from constructor pattern found in the java.time package?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I recently picked up Java and I was exploring the `java.time` package and noticed a, in my view, very nice interface where I could do `ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 1, …)`. Instead of the classical `new ZonedDateTime(2015, 12, 1, …)`.
I saw the same with a `.from` method to create the object from another object.

But just looking at the implementation without understanding *why* it's sometimes `of` and sometimes `from` I feel that I'm missing something. Especially since I'm now keen on using the same pattern for some of my own classes.

This being Java I'm assuming that there's an actual formal proper name for this, and not just something that the implementors of the `java.time` package made on their own. :)

Comment: [Static factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java).

Comment: [Item 1 in Effective Java 2nd Ed](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151) is about static factories, and when to use them. Worth a read.

Comment: Thanks, the links were super helpful! I'm a bit unsure how to close this question now though…

Comment: These are factory methods and the pattern is older than Java. Regarding the naming, usually `of(…)` is used to compose a value while `from(…)` will extract value(s) from a composed value, however, don’t think too much about it, there are plenty of other factory methods with different names. See for example [`Collections.singleton(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The other article talks about what a factory is, but doesn't address the naming conventions.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: can we expect some official words from the developer regarding naming conventions when we reopen the question?

Comment: @Holger We have some informal guidelines, which have been discussed on various OpenJDK lists, but no definitive rules.  So "expecting" an "official" response is too strong, but "hope for useful/authoritative guidelines and advice" doesn't seem out of the question.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: the question is open now…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Tutorials has a chart explaining the various method prefixes employed in the api. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html