# How can I initialize this array beyond the method?

Tags: java, oop

part of my programm:

```
public class Backpack {
    private int maxamount, maxweight;

    public Backpack(int ma, int mw){
    setMaxamount(ma);
    setMaxweight(mw);
}
    public void setMaxamount(int ma){
        this.maxamount=ma;
    }
    public void setMaxweight(int mw){
        this.maxweight=mw;
    }

    Item IA[]=new Item[maxamount];
    int weightA[]=new int[maxamount];
    String nameA[]=new String[maxamount];

    public char addItem(Item I){

    ...
```

When I use this the variable "maxamount" has no value and I can't store values in the array, but when I'm using this:

```
public class Backpack {
    private int maxamount, maxweight;

    public Backpack(int ma, int mw){
    setMaxamount(ma);
    setMaxweight(mw);
}
    public void setMaxamount(int ma){
        this.maxamount=ma;
    }
    public void setMaxweight(int mw){
        this.maxweight=mw;
    }

    public char addItem(Item I){
        Item IA[]=new Item[maxamount];
        int weightA[]=new int[maxamount];
        String nameA[]=new String[maxamount];

    ...
```

,"maxamount" has the value it's supposed to have(from another class), but I need the arrays and the values stored in them in other methods too. So how can I initialize the Arrays out of the method so I can use them for every method?

Comment: If you need them elsewhere don't put them in a method.

Comment: put the init in the constructor

Comment: Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

if you do this

```
Item IA[]=new Item[maxamount];
int weightA[]=new int[maxamount];
String nameA[]=new String[maxamount];
```

*IA*, *weightA*, and *nameA* will be initialized before you even create an instance of the class Backpack

as RC suggested it is a good practice to place those in the constructor...

Remember a Constructor is there to prepare all the elements you need in the object!

Do it right, do it clean!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that Java runs field initializers before it runs the body of the constructor. So when this executes:

```
Item IA[]=new Item[maxamount];
int weightA[]=new int[maxamount];
String nameA[]=new String[maxamount];
```

The field `maxamount` has not yet been assigned. (Another way to think about it—and what the compiler actually does—is that it copies the above initializations to the *start* of the constructor.)

The solution is to move the initialization into the constructor:

```
Item IA[];
int weightA[];
String nameA[];

public Backpack(int ma, int mw){
    setMaxamount(ma);
    setMaxweight(mw);
    IA[]=new Item[maxamount];
    weightA[]=new int[maxamount];
    nameA[]=new String[maxamount];
}
```

By the way, you should not initialize `maxamount` and `maxweight` by calling the setter methods from the constructor. At least you shouldn't be doing that if there's any chance the setter methods might be overridden in a subclass. (See, e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) for why.) Use one of the following approaches:

- make the setter methods `final`;
- make the class `final`;
- call private setter methods (e.g., `_setMaxamount(ma)`) that the public setter methods also use;
- or set the fields directly in the constructor (my usual approach).

For more complicated situations (for instance, where proper initialization *requires* calling an overridable method, such as an abstract method), make the constructor(s) private and use [static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods) or the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create class instances.