# What does the naming convention 'of' mean in Java?

Tags: java

As we can see in Java 8, there are many methods named 'of', like [`Stream.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), [`Optional.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-), and many libraries like [`actorOf`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#actorOf(props:akka.actor.Props,name:String):akka.actor.ActorRef) in Akka.

What does this "of" mean? Is it the English word "of" or an abbreviation for something like "Object Factory"?

Comment: BTW, i would imagine object factory to appear at least as "OF" in a properly named class or method.

Comment: In all examples I can think of in the standard Java APIs, it means "of" in the normal English sense.  For 3rd-party APIs, ask the authors.  (They could be willfully ignoring identifier conventions by making up acronyms and not capitalizing properly.)

Comment: It's just another half-assed attempt to make it sound like English. A `Stream.of(1,2,3)` sounds okay but an `Optional.of(1)` is just weird. `actorOf` is even weirder and should really be called `createActor`.

Comment: Also it is a short word, which is important when you use it a lot.

Comment: `Stream.of(a,b,c)` reads: A **stream** consisting **of** a, b, and c.

Answer (score 110):

It is an English word, yes. It is usually chosen so that the expression will read like an English phrase. For example, `Stream.of(3, 4)` is supposed to look like "stream of three and four," which is sort of like a shortened version of "a stream that is made of the numbers three and four."

Answer (score 45):

As traditionally if you look into wrapper classes, they all contain `valueOf(XXX)` method *to build an instance of the wrapper class of the given value type*.

```
Integer.valueOf(int)
Double.valueOf(double)
Float.valueOf(float)
```

Java is following this naming convention from day 1. Similarly most of Java-8 introduced classes contains this `of(...)` method heavily.

```
Stream.of(...)
LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth)
Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond)
and many more.
```

There are not only `valueOf` or `of` methods available, it has few more methods that serves a specific purpose or type of task inside different classes and they have assigned with a best suitable name representing that task.

- parseXXX(): For parsing given string input. Examples: `Integer.parseInt(str), Double.parseDouble(), Date.parse(datestr)` etc
- get(field): Retrieving a field information from the object. Example: `Calendar.get(field), LocalDate.get(TemporalField)` etc.
- format(): Converting to different representaion. Example: `String.format(), SimpleDateFormat.format(), DateTimeFormatter.format()` etc

These naming conventions are heavily utilized in Java8 DateTime API. Check out this [Method Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html)

Answer (score 38):

It is a common naming convention used for [static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods).

Joshua Bloch mentions the following about the pattern and associated naming conventions in [Effective Java (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors (emphasis added):

> ... 
>   (a) disadvantage of static factory methods is that they are not readily distinguishable from other static methods.  They do not stand out in API documentation in the way that
>   constructors do, so it can be difficult to figure out how to
>   instantiate a class that provides static factory methods instead of
>   constructors. The Javadoc tool may someday draw attention to static
>   factory methods. **In the meantime, you can reduce this disadvantage by
>   drawing attention to static factories in class or interface comments,
>   and by adhering to common naming conventions**. Here are some common
>   names for static factory methods:
>
> - `valueOf`—Returns an instance that has, loosely speaking, the same value as its parameters. Such static factories are effectively
>     type-conversion methods.
> - **`of`—A concise alternative to valueOf, popularized by EnumSet (Item 32).**
>
> ...

So, as others have pointed out, "of" means the English word "of", and is not an abbreviation. But one of the reasons for using this convention is to make it easier to find out if a class provides a factory method because static factories don't show in a separate section in the JavaDocs (compared to constructors).

An added benefit, in my opinion, with using concisely and desciptively named static factories, is that it makes the code [read like prose](http://wiki.c2.com/?ReadsLikeProse), which isn't the case if it's littered with `new` constructor calls.