# Observable List

Tags: java, javafx, constructor, observablelist

when trying to declare a new `ObservableList`:

`ObservableList<Account> userAccounts = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

I am getting an error at `observableArrayList();` which says:

> cannot find symbol, symbol: class `observableArrayList`, location: class `FXCollections`.

Here are my import statements

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
```

And here is my method

```
public ObservableList<Account> getUsersAccounts(int memberID) { 
    ObservableList<Account> userAccounts = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {     
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();            
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE member_id='" + memberID + "'";            
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            Account account = new Account(rs.getInt("member_id"), rs.getString("account_type"), rs.getDouble("balance"));
            userAccounts.add(account);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JDBCManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return userAccounts;
}
```

What am I missing, why can't I declare a new `ObservableList`?

Comment: Get rid of the `new`.

Comment: [`observableArrayList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList--) is a static method, not a class.

Comment: that worked, but why? If i wanted to make an array list for example, ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList();, I would need the new

Comment: you don need to use `new` for a static methods so use: `ObservableList<Account> userAccounts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

Comment: The `new` keyword is used when you call a constructor.

Comment: For a general discussion, read: [What are static factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods)

Comment: @fr33zex, you've been provided 2 nice answers. Find a more useful one for you and accept it! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

An instance can be created directly by using a constructor or implicitly by calling a method where this constructor can be invoked.

In your case, it's a static method. Have a look at these techniques:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> b = Lists.createList();

class Lists {
    public static <T> List<T> createList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. This answer addresses the thing that the OP doesn't understand.

Answer (score 7):

change

```
ObservableList<Account> userAccounts = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

to

```
ObservableList<Account> userAccounts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```