# Android / Dagger2 - How to add bundle arguments ? Inject fragment or use newInstance?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm looking to find a solution on how to inject fragment and pass arguments to it.
And i didn't find any proper solution because injecting the fragment means by the constructor which is not safe for states.

Is there any way to do this, without calling the newInstance pattern ?

Thanks,

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Because Android manages the lifecycle of your Fragment, you should separate the problems of *passing state into the Fragment through its bundle* and *injecting the Fragment with injectable deps*. Usually, the best way to separate these is by providing a [static factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods), which you might be calling the *newInstance pattern*.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

  // Fragments must have public no-arg constructors that Android can call.
  // Ideally, do not override the default Fragment constructor, but if you do
  // you should definitely not take constructor parameters.

  @Inject FieldOne fieldOne;
  @Inject FieldTwo fieldTwo;

  public static YourFragment newInstance(String arg1, int arg2) {
    YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("arg1", arg1);
    bundle.putInt("arg2", arg2);
    yourFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return yourFragment;
  }

  @Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
    // Inject here, now that the Fragment has an Activity.
    // This happens automatically if you subclass DaggerFragment.
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    // Now you can unpack the arguments/state from the Bundle and use them.
    String arg1 = bundle.getString("arg1");
    String arg2 = bundle.getInt("arg2");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note that this is a different type of injection than you may be used to: Rather than getting a Fragment instance by injecting it, you are telling the Fragment to *inject itself later* once it has been attached to an Activity. This example uses [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) for that injection, which uses subcomponents and [members-injection methods](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods) to inject `@Inject-annotated` fields and methods even when Android creates the Fragment instance outside of Dagger's control.

Also note that Bundle is a general key-value store; I've used "arg1" and "arg2" instead of coming up with more creative names, but you can use any String keys you'd like. See [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) and its superclass [BaseBundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle) to see all of the data types Bundle supports in its `get` and `put` methods. This Bundle is also useful for saving Fragment data; if your app is interrupted by a phone call and Android destroys your Activity to save memory, you can use `onSaveInstanceState` to put form field data into the Bundle and then restore that information in `onCreate`.

Finally, note that you don't need to create a static factory method like `newInstance`; you could also have your consumers create a `new YourFragment()` instance and pass in a particular Bundle design themselves. However, at that point the Bundle structure becomes a part of your API, which you may not want. By creating a static factory method (or Factory object or other structure), you allow the Bundle design to be an implementation detail of your Fragment, and provide a documented and well-kept structure for consumers to create new instances.

Comment: Hi Jeff,
So it means i have to create separate different entities for each arguments ?
How can i achieve to add several primary types like String ?
Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDot Your static factory method (e.g. `newInstance`) can take as many parameters as it wants, and Bundle is a key-value store (like a Map) where you can insert any kind of data you'd like. I've only listed one argument here ("arg") but you can put in as many as you'd like. See [the Bundle docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) for all of the getters and setters it supports.

Comment: Sorry i missread your first comment, i meant the 2 inject fields. But nevermind.
So if i understand well, you are saying we can't inject a fragment with arguments ? We have to go with the static factory method newInstance ?

Comment: @JohnDot I'm saying _regardless of arguments you should never use constructor injection on Fragment_ (or any other object Android can create and destroy on its own, which includes Application, Activity, View, and Service). You can still inject a Fragment, but the right place to do that is in `onAttach` as above. The right way to pass state and parameters ("arguments") into a Fragment is using a Bundle; you might choose to encapsulate that with a static factory method. (You could also just require your consumers to call `new` and then call `setArguments` with a particular Bundle structure.)

Comment: @JohnDot I've updated the answer to include some of the information in the comments, and to clarify how the Bundle logic and DI code works.

Comment: So, to explain a bit more what i'm doing :
I do this in my module :
`@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun testFragment(): TestFragment`

And this in my activity :
`@Inject lateinit var testFragment: TestFragment`

And my TestFragment :
`class TestFragment @Inject constructor() : DaggerFragment()`

What i'm doing is a bad practice then ?
I don't know how to inject my fragment inside my activity without the constructor injection...

Comment: @JohnDot There are three types of objects: Objects that don't need DI (e.g. Strings and Lists and data objects and other _newables_), objects that need DI that you get from a factory (like a Component or Provider), and objects where you call `new` and _they inject themselves_. Fragments in dagger.android are the third category: you don't need to worry about getting them from the graph in your Activity; you can call `new` or `newInstance` instead, and then in `onAttach` that call to `AndroidSupportInject.inject(this)` will _let the fragment inject itself_.