# How to make a singleton abstract base class which all derived classes together can instantiate only one instance? (Java)

Tags: java, singleton, abstract-class

My problem is that I want to process a bigger HTML page from web, with Jsoup. Once I have the HTML file, I want to write the content to a file, so I don't have to make the internet connection every time (for developing and testing this static HTML is enough for me).

From that class, which contains this JSoup document I want to have a singleton instance.

My idea was to make a base class, `Page` and two derived class from that (`PageFromFile`, `PageWithHttp`). 
In that case, `Page` should not be instantiated, but it should contain one abstract method, the `getInstance`. This seems to be a contradiction.

Of course, there is the trivial way to do that: I have only the `Page` class, it has a field whether it was readed from file or from the web, and handle things accordingly, but this doesn't seem to be an elegant way. (There would be an if statement in the most of the functions).

I have two questions:

1. How would you implement my problem?
2. How is it possible to make it work in the way I mentioned before? So for example there is abstract `Animal` class, `Dog` and `Cat` extends that. How can I instantiate only one `Animal`, either `Dog` or `Cat`?

Comment: You're going to have to explain yourself clearer. Perhaps with more realistic examples than "base" and "derived".

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods