# How to compare two utc datetimes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a date like this in DB:

1. `2020-10-21T00:06:06.000Z` which I want to compare with current date and time

If current date and time has past the date from DB then trigger some action.

```js
let oldDate = `2020-10-21T00:06:06.000Z`;
let dateNow = new Date();
console.log('oldDate ', new Date(oldDate));
console.log('date now', dateNow);
console.log('oldDate time', new Date(oldDate).getTime());
console.log('newDate time', dateNow.getTime());

const schedule = dateNow.getTime() > new Date(oldDate).getTime() ? "trigger now" : "trigger later";
console.log('scheduled for:  ', schedule);
```

I am trying to check if dateTime is past old dateTime but is this is right approach or any other better solutions?

Comment: ISO 8601 timestamps will naturally sort themseves into "newer" and "older" if you check for "less than" and "greater than": `"2020-01-20" > "2020-02-20" //false` while `"2020-01-20" < "2020-02-20" //true`

Comment: @VLAZ If I don't use `getTime()` result is invalid

Comment: Then you don't have ISO 8601 formatted dates.

Comment: @VLAZ `2020-10-21T00:06:06.000Z` ??

Comment: If you're getting an invalid result, then your formats are wrong somewhere. That's all I can say - lexicographic sorting also acts as chronological for ISO 8601 strings. That's part of the design behind the standard. You receiving wrong results means that there is something non-standard happening. [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/penekamezu/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough reputation to make a comment. Did you try this?

```
let oldDate = '2020-10-21T00:06:06.000Z';
const schedule = Date.now() - Date.parse(oldDate) > 0 ? "trigger now" : "trigger later";
```

Comment: Yes I just did and now trying to understand difference between `Date.parse(oldDate)` and `new Date(oldDate).getTime()`

Comment: Well the first idea and the most obvious point is the Date.parse is a static method whilst with new Date() approach you construct a new instance. Subtle difference though.

Comment: Date.parse() also creates a new instance - it's just a static factory method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/929273/9150652

Comment: @MauriceNino Date.parse() returns a primitive type number. Not an instance. So IMHO static factory pattern does not relate that case.

Comment: Ahhh should have looked into what Date.parse() does lol, my mistake. Caught offguard by that "subtle difference", so I thought both return a date object. Youre right - but the difference is not so subtle :P