# How to type-cast a nested Array of Objects into a nested List of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, casting

Cannot create nested ArrayList from Array in Java

I am trying to create a nested list from an array.

But I have a problem while converting `Object` to `String`:

```
Object[] array = new Object[] {
                    new String[] {"add, hack"},
                    new String[] {"add, hackerrank"},
                    new String[] {"find, hac"},
                    new String[] {"find, hak"}
};

List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList((array.toString())));
```

So, how can I convert it properly?

Here is the method that reserves the `List<List<String>>`:

```
public static List<Integer> contacts(List<List<String>> queries) {
    for (List<String> query : queries) {
        String operation = query.get(0); // --> gives "add, hack" (I expect "add")
        String word = query.get(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should do a loop for the outer array. or use a stream.

Comment: Are you missing quotes in your sample data? Did you intend single strings or pairs of strings?

Comment: I intend pairs of string, but they are also an array. So, I iterate over 4 element in that array and each of them has 2 words as another array.

Comment: A comma-separated string does not an array make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution assuming you want to start from Object[] array - first transforms to list of String[] using casting and then maps every String[] to List:

```
    List<String[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object o : array)
        arrList.add((String[]) o);

    List<List<String>> strList = arrList.stream()
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "add, hack" is one string - so either you need to input as "add", "hack" or split it after retrieval

Comment: Yes, but I need to retrieve as `["add hack"]` instead of  `"add hack"`

Answer (score 1):

Every array inside the source array in your code like `new String[] {"add, hack"}` is treated as `Object` - that's all the compiler knows about it because `array` has been declared as `Object[]` (i.e. array of objects, not array of arrays objects, or array of arrays of strings).

`Arrays.asList(array.toString())` - creates a list with a single element of type `String`. And when you invoke `toString()` on an array of any type, you will obtain a string containing the array's type and hash-based sequence of symbols after the at-sign `@`. In order to get  a string representation of the array contents, you need to use static method `toString()` of the `Arrays` class.

This way you can approach the problem of casting an array of `Object` type

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] array =  new Object[][]{
        new String[] {"add, hack"},
        new String[] {"add, hackerrank"},
        new String[] {"find, hac"},
        {"find, hak"} // you can omit new String[] when assigning array while at the same time with initialization
    };    

    List<List<String>> list = arraysToList(array, String.class);

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Generic method for casting, that expects a `Class` object as a parameter:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> arraysToList(Object[][] array, Class<T> clazz) {
    return Stream.of(array)
        .map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).map(clazz::cast).toList())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Output**

```
[[add, hack], [add, hackerrank], [find, hac], [find, hak]]
```

Your Question is unclear as to your goal. Perhaps you want to generate text in a specific format. If so, add a method to the record class `Query` that returns a `String` object in your desired format.

---

If you need to split a single string containing non-alphabetic symbols into separate words, you can make use of the `split()` method:

```
str.split("[^\\p{Alpha}]+"); // returns an array of strings comprised of alphabetic symbols only
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But anyhow, the format is changed and the array is received as `"add, hack"` instead of `["add, hack"]` in the line of `query.get(0)`. Please see my update and could you share your opinion on where I am missing?

Comment: @VivaUkraine Got it, there are two ways to deal with it. **1.** Define nested arrays like that `new String[] {"add", "hack"} - i.e. containing two string instead of a single comma separated string. **2.** Split all strings on non-alphabetic symbols while creating the list. Both fixes are easy to apply. If your source array **must** contain such a single string arrays (i.e. you are not in control of this incoming data) **it's worth to emphasize** in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Use objects, not lists of arrays

The other Answers seem to be correct about your various problems. I will look at the bigger picture… Your design approach has ignored the the best feature of Java: [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Your query pieces should be packaged as a class, a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Query ( String verb , String noun ) {}
```

Apparently you are starting with a [comma-separated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) as inputs. So add a [static factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929021/642706) to parse each input.

```
record Query ( String verb , String noun ) {
    // Factory method to instantiate `Query` object by parsing input string containing a pair of comma-separated values.
    public static Query parse( final String input ) {
        String[] parts = input.split( ", " ) ;
        return new Query ( parts[0] , parts[1] ) ;
    }
}
```

Skip the arrays, and use `List` or `Set` for their convenience.

```
List< Query > queries = 
    List.of(
        Query.parse( "add, hack" ) ,  // Instantiates a `Query` object. 
        Query.parse( "add, hackerrank" ) , 
        Query.parse( "find, hac" ) ,
        Query.parse( "find, hak" )
    )
;
```

### Generating text

Report contents.

```
System.out.println( "queries = " + queries );
```

> queries = [Query[verb=add, noun=hack], Query[verb=add, noun=hackerrank], Query[verb=find, noun=hac], Query[verb=find, noun=hak]]

Your Question is not clear as to its end goal. If your goal is to generate text in a particular format, add a method to your class. Here we add a method called `report`.

```
String report ( ) { return String.format( "{ %s, %s }" , this.verb , this.noun ); }
```

To use that `report` method, loop your objects, generating text for each.

```java
queries.forEach( query -> System.out.println( query.report() ) );
```

```
{ add, hack }
{ add, hackerrank }
{ find, hac }
{ find, hak }
```

---

Caveat: In real work, we would do more to verify and validate. For example we would validate our input data to make sure the input string is [non-null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), non-[blank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()), and composed of two parts. I omitted such code to keep the demo short and on-point.

Comment: Very nice usage of records!

Answer (score 0):

You can `stream` the array and then collect to a `List`:

```
Object[] array = new Object[] {
            new String[] {"add, hack"},
            new String[] {"add, hackerrank"},
            new String[] {"find, hac"},
            new String[] {"find, hak"}};

List<List<String>> list = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(String[].class::cast)
        .map(arr -> arr[0].split(", "))
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[[add, hack], [add, hackerrank], [find, hac], [find, hak]]
```

With JDK 16+ you can do:

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(String[].class::cast)
        .map(arr -> arr[0].split(", "))
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .toList();
```

Comment: That's because your original array has element `new String[] {"add, hack"}` instead of `new String[] {"add", "hack"}`. To achieve this you can split the strings. I updated my answer with this modification.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be an "array of arrays" it would need to be a 2-dimensional array:

```java
String[][] arrays = new String[][] {new String[] {"add, hack"}, ...}
```

Then you could convert each array inside the array into an item in the list

```java
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] array : arrays) {
    list.add(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```