# Java interface that returns objects with its own type

Tags: java, static-factory, concreteclass

I was looking at an interface that is built into Java, and noticed that it has methods which return objects of its own type.

Specifically, the [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) interface has a method `range` which returns an IntStream object (i.e. some object that implements IntStream). This method can be used by only importing the interface, as follows:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream s = IntStream.range(0,10);
        System.out.println(s.average());
    }
}
```

It therefore seems that 'under the hood' the interface is choosing an implementation for me, and allowing me to use it. How exactly is this working?

Crucially, how would I do the same thing? If I wanted to export an interface that can instantiate objects of its own type, so that a user could simply import my interface and it would drag along my implementation, how would I do this? Or is this only a special privilege of interfaces built into Java?

Comment: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntStream.java

Comment: This is a choice made in the implementation of the static method `IntStream.range`.

Comment: See: [*What are static factory methods?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929021/642706). Notice their extensive use in the *java.time* classes such as `LocalDate.of( year , month , day )`.  See [naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range` is a static method of the `IntStream` interface that returns an instance of a class that implements `IntStream`. Take a look in the example below.

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public static class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        @Override 
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println( "i'm an implementing class!" );
        }
    }

    public static MyInterface createMagicInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public void doSomething();

}

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        MyInterface mi = MyInterface.createMagicInstance();
        mi.doSomething();
    }
}
```

In my example I tried to design something self-contained, but implementations of `createMagicInstance` may vary. You don't need to implement the returning type as a static inner class. I would recomend you to take a look at the source code of `IntStream` class of OpenJDK: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntStream.java

Comment: I see. So crucially, the implementation would need to be bundled with the interface (i.e. in the same file)? And I'm guessing if we made the implementing class private, this would allow us to hide it from others and force them to rely on the interface?

Comment: No, the implementation may vary. In the example you can't have a private static class, since it's an interface and in interfaces everything must be public.

Comment: Perhaps add a mention that, technically, the concrete implementation class need not be nested within the interface. Such nesting is a design choice, not a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The "interface" is not returning anything.

[`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) is a `static` method that returns an `IntStream`.

It has little to do with the `IntStream` interface and would work equally well if defined in another class.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [definition of IntStream.range](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) you would be able to see that `range` is an [static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of `IntStream`, which means, you don't need to have an instance of IntStream to call it, you can just directly invoke it as you are doing in the piece of code you put as example. How can you do it? Just define an interface with an static method that returns an object of that interface type. You can also check the [source code of IntStream](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntStream.java#L1041) and see the implementation

```
public static IntStream rangeClosed(int startInclusive, int endInclusive) {
    if (startInclusive > endInclusive) {
        return empty();
    } else {
        return StreamSupport.intStream(
                new Streams.RangeIntSpliterator(startInclusive, endInclusive, true), false);
    }
}
```