# Best way to deal with some classes implementing comparable and some not in a Binary search tree

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am looking for suggestions on how to handle some possible elements implementing comparable and some not.

I am currently trying to do it like this

```java
class BinaryTree<E> { 
  private Comparator<E> comparator;
  public <T extends Comparable<E>>() BinaryTree() {
    comparator = (T a, T b) -> a.compareTo(b)
  }


  public BinaryTree(Comparator<E> comparator) { 
    this.comparator = comparator
  }
}

//rest of the class (add, remove etc)
```

And then the comparator variable is used. I cant get it to compile  tho.

Comment: If you get compiler errors, your question should include copies of those errors.

Comment: How does java's own library do it? There's no mention of Comparable in the [API method declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), if you didn't provide a comparator and the element is not comparable, it blows up with a ClassCastException at runtime.

Comment: How would a binary tree work w/ uncomparable items?

Answer (score 1):

Just check and see if a comparator has been provided.  If so, use it.  Otherwise, `presume` that the objects implement it.  The downside is that if the objects don't implement it you will get a runtime exception instead of a compiler error.

```
class BinaryTree<E> {

    private Comparator<E> comparator = null;

  
    public BinaryTree() {
    }
    
    public BinaryTree(Comparator<E> myComparator) {
          this.comparator = myComparator;
    }
    
    public void traverse() {
        if (comparator != null) {
            //use it
        } else {
            // compare Objects presuming they implement comparable.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally this use case is handled by casting. See [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet--) for example. One way to do it would be like this:

```
public BinaryTree() {
  this((e1, e2) -> ((Comparable<E>) e1).compareTo(e2));
}
```

Naturally, this will throw [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) at runtime, if you try to add elements, which do not implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

I would do it with a [static factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods). Like this you can declare the type variable to be bound as a subclass of Comparable:

```
public class BinaryTree<E> {
  
  private Comparator<E> comparator;

  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> BinaryTree<T> fromComparable() {
    return new BinaryTree<>(Comparable::compareTo);
  }

  public BinaryTree(Comparator<E> comparator) { 
    this.comparator = comparator;
  }
}
```

The compiler now won't allow you to create a `BinaryTree` with non-comparable elements:

```
BinaryTree<Integer> tree1 = BinaryTree.fromComparable(); //compiles succesfully
BinaryTree<NonComparableClass> tree2 = BinaryTree.fromComparable(); //compilation error
```