# Factory method which method

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have trouble understanding factory method pattern. From the example here: http://worldwardiary.com/history/Factory_method_pattern#Using_the_factory_pattern and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/806942/2420939:

```
public class ImageReaderFactory 
{
    public static ImageReader getImageReader( InputStream is ) 
    {
        int imageType = figureOutImageType( is );

        switch( imageType ) 
        {
            case ImageReaderFactory.GIF:
                return new GifReader( is );
            case ImageReaderFactory.JPEG:
                return new JpegReader( is );
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Which one is de-facto "factory method": getImageReader() or the "<<" method of the GifReader class?

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) and [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) and

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, factory methods encapsulate the creation of objects. **They** create complex objects for you so you don't have to bother.

In your example:

```
public class ImageReaderFactory {
    public static ImageReader getImageReader(InputStream is) {
        int imageType = figureOutImageType( is );
         switch( imageType ) {
            case ImageReaderFactory.GIF:
                return new GifReader( is );
            case ImageReaderFactory.JPEG:
                return new JpegReader( is );
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Who's creating the `ImageReader` objects (calling their constructors) and returning them? Neither `figureOutImageType()` or the method of the `GifReader` class (or the others `JpegReader` or possibly `PngReader`, `TiffReader`, `etcReader`...).

**Ultimately**, `getImageReader()` is creating them for you. This is the method you call asking ***"hey, create me a `ImageReader`, please"*** and it does the rest.

So, at best, `public static ImageReader getImageReader(InputStream is) {}` is the closest (see update below) to a factory method.

---

#### Update:

Bear in mind this design is **not strictly** a "Factory Method Pattern". This [**is** presented as a ***variant*** of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method#Encapsulation).

The reason for this has been discussed in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806911/is-this-factory-method-creation-pattern), so allow me to just [quote one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811661/1850609) (slightly adapted):

> (...) this snippet is not a *proper* implementation of the "Factory Method OO Design Pattern", since it does not satisfy "a class defer instantiation to subclasses." Though, personally I would freely refer to this solution as "factory method". 
> To make it *real* factory method pattern, you need to allow the method to be overridden by subclasses. I.e. factory class (**`ImageReaderFactory`**) needs to be extensible (i.e. non-**`static`**), and **`getImageReader`** needs to be **`abstract`**.

Comment: sry, I meant "getImageReader() or the "<<" method of the GifReader class" -- see edit to my question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"`<<` method of the `GifReader` class"*?

Comment: the returned class GifReader/JpegReader will have a method, called read() , or c++-ish "<<" operator.

Comment: No, `GifReader.read()` or `JpegReader.read()` would just provide you the functionality of reading the image. Notice that what that snippet wants is a `ImageReader`, not an `Image`, so the factory is the one whos building `ImageReader`s.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with acdcjunior's answer. What he describes is plain **factory pattern**. 
**Factory method pattern** involves defining *interface* in order for:

1. *concrete implementer* could implement
2. *client* could use to both create *product* (possibly implementing some interface) and abstract over details of product creation.

**UPDATE:** [Factory method article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method) from wikipedia:

> The essence of this pattern is to "Define an interface for creating an
>   object, but let the classes that implement the interface decide which
>   class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer
>   instantiation to subclasses."

(see also code example there).

**UPDATE2:**

Answering your question:

> Which one is de-facto "factory method": getImageReader() or the "<<"
>   method of the GifReader class?

None of them, since there is no abstraction involved. `getImageReader` is just a "method of the factory", but not "factory method pattern".